# Angular routing fails on remote server working locally

Tags: angular, iis, routes, angular-routing, angular9

I have a very simple project that has the following routing.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "start", component: StartComponent },
  { path: "sub01", component: Sub01Component },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/start", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", component: StartComponent }
];
```

When I run it locally using `ng serve` and browsing to *localhost:4200*, I get to see the starting page's contents and the URL is rewritten to *localhost:4200/start*, just as expected. Then, I produced a semi-final version by *ng build* and put in the *dist* directory on my IIS. Browsing to the address of the application produces the same result as above. I can also confirm that browsing to e.g. the images' URLs produces the expected result too.

The difference, as I noticed, is that locally, it works to reload the page (i.e. surfing to *localhost:4200/start*) while the same operation on the remote fails, giving me 404 (so surfing to *http://address.that-worked-just.now/start* works not). Since I can access other URLs than just the root, it seems to me that it's only the routing that won't work.

I'm a bit flabbergasted by this behavior and not sure how to diagnose it further. The only difference I'm aware of within my reach is that locally, I serve the app using the default Angular CLI while on the remote, I have IIS that serves *index.html* containing the script. So I figure that once the document is produced to the client, everything else happens on the client. (The app is really limited and there's no interaction with the server, no services etc. as it's basically a landing page, at least for now).

Am I missing something that should be declared in any of the config files? Or is it a weird misbehavior likely to occur due to some firewall policy or such? I'm not sure how to determine that and I rather assume that I've done something stupid than blame the server team. Given the description above, what more can be inferred?

Comment: Have you configured push-state routing (i.e. fall-back to `index.html` for missing routes) on IIS? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I though I did by the last line of the route config in my question.

Comment: That only handles routes that *actually make it to the Angular app*. You're getting 404 from IIS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, bummer. I see your point. I'll need to fight with the server guys then. I have zero access to the server in this case. Will you post that as an answer? If not, I'll remove the question as it servers little value the way it is now.

Comment: I can't really give a proper answer because I don't know how to configure push-state routing on IIS, and there seem to be a few dupes on Angular routing failing server-side in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS has its own routing system. So when we host Angular in IIS, Angular routing will be failed, because IIS doesn’t understand the Angular routing and will be looking for a resource that matches the route and it gives you 404 error.

To resolve the issue you could try one of the below solutions:

Use the IIS URL rewrite rule to set the routing:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

Another way is to add the error page for 404 to redirect to /index.html.

[image]

Comment: @KonradViltersten i will update the post as you suggested. thanks for the suggestion.